# Parsing array in Swift2.2

Tags: swift

How to get body and title data from the below response. I'm totally stuck

```
[aps: {

    alert =     {
        body = test123;
        title = test123;
    };
 }, 
 gcm.message_id: 0:4a]
```

Comment: if let dict = userInfo[0] as? [String:AnyObject] {
           print(dict)
        }

Comment: I'm asking is, the Response you have added is showing from the `print(dict)`?

Comment: @Nirav I'm getting nil value for that. can u help me out

Comment: Check my answer once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with notification then you need to access the data like this way.

```
if let info = notification.userInfo as? [String: AnyObject],
   let apsDic = info["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject], 
   let alertDic = info["alert"] as? [String: AnyObject] { 
      if let body = alertDic["body"] as? String {
          print(body)
      }
      if let title = alertDic["title"] as? String {
          print(title)
      }
}
```

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Welcome mate :)